# where quagga stores BGP Table in Linux file system

Tags: linux, fedora, quagga

I am using quagga with fedora 18. I successfully formed the neighbor relationship between the peers. I can also see the result of sh ip bgp command.

My question is in which file does the quagga saves the bgp table entries in the linux file system. Like the kernel routing table is located at the /proc/net/route.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Quagga doesn't save the BGP routing table anywhere except in the memory of the `bgpd` daemon.  There is no way to access it other than going through the `vtysh` command or connecting to the `bgpd` daemon's control socket.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of ways to access or assess what's in quagga BGP tables.

One way is vtyssh, another is to obtain the table through snmp (quite slow) and a third way is to dump the tables in an MRT file.

Here is an example on how to configure quagga so to be able to dump the tables.

http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/docs/docs-multi/Dump-BGP-packets-and-table.html#Dump-BGP-packets-and-table

Once they are dumped you will have to somehow analyze the file. My favorite one is https://github.com/iTransformers/javaMrt2Graphml which will generate you an internet BGP peering map from the captured dump.